# node.js conditional stream pipe

Tags: node.js, hapi.js, node-streams

I'm trying to understand how best to conditionally pipe a stream to a `Transform` or similar **without** the use of a 3rd party lib.

Ideally I'd like to do something like this

```
const transformA, transformB = // my transforms
const booleanA, booleanB = // my various conditions

const stream = new Readable()
stream.push('...') // my content

return stream
         .pipe(booleanA && transformA)
         .pipe(booleanB && transformB)
```

I've attempted this using libs like `detour-stream`, `ternary-stream` and others but I've encountered various strange side effects where transforms are being invoked when they shouldn't, throwing errors etc, and its left me wondering about how people accomplish this type of thing without the added complexity of those libs.

In the interim I've solved this by just taking an imperative approach, reassigning the stream on each condition.

```
let stream = // get my stream

if (condition) stream = stream.pipe(someTransform)
if (otherCondition) stream = stream.pipe(otherTransform)

return stream
```

This is fine, but I'm still curious if the immutable and functional approach can be done

Thanks for looking & reading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there's no built-in support for conditional pipes, an alternative to your approach without any third-party modules is using `.pipeline`

```
const stream = require('stream');
const pipeline = util.promisify(stream.pipeline);

const read = new stream.Readable()

const pipes = [
  booleanA && transformA,
  booleanB && transformB
].filter(Boolean); // remove empty pipes

await pipeline(
   read,
   ...pipes
);
```

Since `.pipeline` takes N transform streams, you can make use of spread operator from an already filtered array of pipes.

In case you want to return the last piped stream, you can drop the promisify version of `pipeline`.

```
return pipeline(
   read,
   ...pipes,
   () => {}
)
```

Comment: I've implemented this and the result of `await pipeline(readableStream, pipe1, pipe2)` is undefined, but debugging inside those transforms reveals they are being invoked - does your answer make any assumptions about the `stream` argument?

Comment: but you're using `pipe1` & `pipe2`, that's not how my code works, do `console.log(pipes)`.

Comment: sorry, to be clear I'm getting the same result when I invoke `pipeline` with a stream and a single transform `const thisIsUndefined = await pipeline(stream, pipe1)` -- my environment doesn't support destructuring but I understand that pipes is an array of transforms -- I think your code should be effectively the same as `pipeline.call(this, [stream].concat(pipes))` yes?

Comment: maybe there's an error because you're using `stream` for your read stream & I used it for requiring `stream = require('stream')` to `promisify` pipeline.

Comment: hmm still testing this -- and I don't think thats the issue, I'm importing like so `import { pipeline as streamPipeline } from 'stream';` - if I can't get this to work I'll revert to some kind of simple sandbox example if possible.

Comment: do: `console.log(pipes)` and make sure only the right transform stream is present. I guarentee that that code is working, only the streams which `booleanX` is true is being piped into.

Comment: @James what you want is `.apply` not `.call`.

Comment: So the problem is that I was expecting the promisified pipeline to return a value, and it doesn't. To get your solution to return a stream, you can return a promise, then resolve the pipeline inside the callback argument. https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v12.x/docs/api/stream.html#stream_stream_pipeline_streams_callback

Comment: Also I'm using node 12 (which I should have specified) in which pipeline doesn't appear to support Transforms as args :(

Comment: I'm using Node 12, and it supports transform as args. The above code is fully working on Node 12.

Comment: Either provide a full snippet or I can't help you, since the code I submitted works fine, there's something off with yours, without seeing it it's impossible for me to help you